# About "circular reference", I used weak_ptr but memory leak still happened

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, circular-reference, weak-ptr

I read:

[How to avoid memory leak with shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826902/how-to-avoid-memory-leak-with-shared-ptr?fbclid=IwAR32xoP3zxQps_LPWhnuQRUwWd3yBg0xDAuZc0jONy7-60AH9iSitX591-o)

I know that I need to use **weak_ptr** to avoid **circular reference** .

So I created a little program to play **circular reference**.

Following object(spyder) will be invoke

```cpp
class spyder {
 public:
  spyder(std::string _name): 
    m_name(_name), finger(nullptr)
  {  }
  inline const std::string ask_name() const{
    return m_name;
  }
  std::shared_ptr<spyder> finger;
 private:
  std::string m_name;
};
```

I invoke **spyder** in my main code with shared_ptr and weak_ptr:

```
int main(){
  auto sA = std::make_shared<spyder>("A");
  auto sB = std::make_shared<spyder>("B");
  std::weak_ptr<spyder> wp_sA(sA);
  std::weak_ptr<spyder> wp_sB(sB);  
  sA->finger = wp_sB.lock();
  sB->finger = wp_sA.lock();
}
```

Above code has memory leak happened(use valgrind to check).

```
==20753== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20753== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20753== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20753== Command: ./t
==20753== 
==20753== 
==20753== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20753==     in use at exit: 128 bytes in 2 blocks
==20753==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 72,832 bytes allocated
==20753== 
==20753== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20753==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==20753==    indirectly lost: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==20753==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20753==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20753==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20753== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20753== 
==20753== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20753== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But after I modify above code as:

```cpp
int main(){
  spyder sA("A"), sB("B");
  std::weak_ptr<spyder> wp_sA( std::make_shared<spyder>("A") ) ;
  std::weak_ptr<spyder> wp_sB( std::make_shared<spyder>("B") );
  sA.finger = wp_sB.lock();
  sB.finger = wp_sA.lock();
}
```

The memory leak hasn't happened,

```
==20695== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20695== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20695== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20695== Command: ./t
==20695== 
==20695== 
==20695== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20695==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20695==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 72,832 bytes allocated
==20695== 
==20695== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20695== 
==20695== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20695== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I feel confused about this.

Comment: What happens *after* the `lock` calls? Do you ever unlock the weak pointers? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and also copy-paste the full output of Valgrind from that example.

Comment: Also I think you're misunderstanding something, in the first example what you're really doing is equal to `sA->finger = sB; sB->finger = sA;`. You need to make the `finger` members `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude : I've updated utput of Valgrind. command is ```valgrind --leak-check=summary ./t.out ```

Comment: **You cannot fix a circular reference design issue with weak references.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You haven't solved the circular dependency at all.**

#### In your first version,

`sA` is managed by a `shared_ptr` and it stores a `shared_ptr` to `sB`. `sB` in turn is managed by `shared_ptr` and stores a `shared_ptr` to `sA`. This means their reference count can never go to 0.

Instead, `finger` should be of type `std::weak_ptr` and you should only `lock()` it before you need to use it.

```
class spyder {
 public:
  spyder(std::string _name): 
    m_name(_name), finger()
  {  }
  inline const std::string ask_name() const{
    return m_name;
  }
  std::weak_ptr<spyder> finger;
 private:
  std::string m_name;
};

int main(){
  auto sA = std::make_shared<spyder>("A");
  auto sB = std::make_shared<spyder>("B");
  sA->finger = sB;
  sB->finger = sA;
}
```

---

#### Your second version

constructs `weak_ptr` from a temporary `shared_ptr`, which means immidiately after construction your `weak_ptr` is `expired()`. Both `sA.finger` and `sB.finger` store `nullptr` in this version (but there's no memory leak).

Comment: Hi @Yksisarvinen: Thanks your reply. After I modify **std::weak_ptr<spyder> finger;** this code cannot compile, see std::weak_ptr<spyder> finger; see **cpp.sh/7a2fm**

Comment: @curlywei My bad, didn't run the code before posting. Default constructor for `std::weak_ptr` (and `std::shared_ptr` as well) will initialize it with `nullptr`. You can even omit it from initializer list. Editted the answer now

Comment: After I removed **nullptr**, this code work normally. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Your code leaks because it *still* has a circular reference. `sA -> sA::finger -> sB -> sB::finger -> sA` The main point of `std::weak_ptr` is to **store** reference to the pointer. To avoid memory leakage your class source should look like this:

```
class spyder {
 public:
  spyder(std::string _name): 
    m_name(_name), finger(nullptr)
  {  }
  inline const std::string ask_name() const{
    return m_name;
  }
  std::weak_ptr<spyder> finger;
 private:
  std::string m_name;
};
```

Comment: Hi @Ari0nhh: As Yksisarvinen said, **finger(nullptr)** should be **finger()**

Comment: @curlywei For the record, format _inline_ code in comments (or in questions/answers) using single backticks like so: \`myCode\` becomes `myCode`. It's better than using **bold**.