# Concept about Reference Count and Circular Reference in C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, circular-reference

I known how `weak_ptr` is used, I read the following post:

[About “circular reference”, I used weak_ptr but memory leak still happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851897/about-circular-reference-i-used-weak-ptr-but-memory-leak-still-happened)

But there is a concept I can't understand yet.

I will demonstrate `shared_ptr`'s created and released as I understand it:

---

## 1. `shared_ptr` `pa` created

`reference_count` of `pa` should be `0`.
Because no `shared_ptr` points to `pa` .

```cpp
{/*scope 1*/

  shared_ptr<int> pa;
  // reference_count_pa = 0
}
```

## 2. I assign new `shared_ptr<int>` `pb` to `pa` in another scope

```
{/*scope 1*/

  shared_ptr<int> pa;

  {/*scope 2*/

    shared_ptr<int> pb = pa;
    // reference_count_pa = 1
    // reference_count_pb = 0
  }
}
```

`reference_count` of `pa` should be `1` because `shared_ptr` `pb` points to `pa` .

`reference_count` of `pb` should be `0` because no `shared_ptr` points to `pb` .

## 3. Now, a simple `Circular Reference`:

as is demonstrated in [About “circular reference”, I used weak_ptr but memory leak still happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851897/about-circular-reference-i-used-weak-ptr-but-memory-leak-still-happened):

```
{/*scope 1*/

  shared_ptr<int> pa;

  {/*scope 2*/

    shared_ptr<int> pb = pa;
    pa = pb; //circular reference
    // reference_count_pa = 1
    // reference_count_pb = 1
  }
}
```

`reference_count` of `pa` should be `1` because `shared_ptr` `pb` points to `pa`

`reference_count` of `pb` should be `1` because `shared_ptr` `pa` points to `pb`

## 4. In the end of `scope 2`

`pb` is deleted because program walks out of `scope 2` .

`reference_count` of `pa` is `0` now, because no `shared_ptr` points to `pa` .

`reference_count` of `pb` is still `1`.

## 5. In the end of `scope 1`

`reference_count` of `pb` is `0` now because no `shared_ptr` points to `pb` .

---

The above steps are the reference_count as I understand it.

`pa` and `pb` are being deleted normally.

I'm confused.

Can anyone correct my error in the above steps?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no circular reference there. Also, you're not actually allocating memory anywhere so the reference count is zero everywhere.

Comment: The reference count tells you how many `shared_ptr`s are sharing an object. `shared_ptr<int> pb = pa;` does not mean that `pb` points to `pa`, but that both `pb` and `pa` share the same `int`, making the reference count 2.

Comment: You can check `pa.use_count()` and `pb.use_count()` to see the reference count yourself

Comment: There are many "should be" assumptions here that you could take a few minutes to verify.

Comment: Hi Kerndog73: I forget to use `std::make_shared<Node>`

Comment: About reference counting: imagine that all shared pointers just point to a proxy object that holdes the shared pointer and a reference counter. Creating a new shared pointer with a raw pointer would create a new proxy object, reference count 1, creating a new shared pointer from another would just increment the reference count. Destruction is simple: if reference count is 1, destroy proxy and shared object, otherwise just decrement reference count. Assignment gets a bit more complicated, combines both destruction and construction, but basic idea remains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone correct my error in above step ?

Firstly, that isn't a circular reference. Secondly there isn't any reference counting in your code, because you have no `int` to count references to.

A circular reference is of the form

```
struct Node {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> a = std::make_shared<Node>();
    std::shared_ptr<Node> b = std::make_shared<Node>();

    a->next = b;
    b->next = a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand what `circular reference` now

Comment: `a->next = a;` is even a shorter cycle ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `use_count` when you write `reference_count`? The latter cant be found in cpp-reference.

The answer is  a `shared_ptr` counts the number of all (this one and other) managed pointers, that points to the same object (pointee). Hence, all managed pointers pointing to the same object will return the same `use_count`. (This adresses your conclusion of 2.).

Your "circular" reference" in 3 isn't a circular reference, but two shared pointers pointing to nothing. I recomend `std::make_shared>` to create an (managed)Object that is managed be a shared pointer. BTW, a week pointer is pointing to a managed Object that is aware of the existence of this Object.

Just read the manual, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr. Here you find the description of `use_count`:

```
long use_count() const noexcept;
```

Returns the number of different shared_ptr instances (this included) managing the current object. If there is no managed object, ​0​ is returned.